# Ruby on Rails: Common method available for controllers and views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been working with Ruby on Rails for a short time. Recently I implemented an authentication system for my application. I made a method available on 'application_helper.rb' to retrieve the current logged user (method called current_user).

The method just retrieves my `User` object if the `session[:user_id]` variable is present.

However I face the following problem.

1. If I place the `current_user` method in '*application_helper.rb*', my **controllers** can't make use of it
2. If I place the `current_user` method in '*application_controller.rb*', my **views** can't make use of it

What's the best approach to solve this problem? The easy way would be duplicate my code in both controller and helper, but I know there is a better and more correct way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a common and well-solved problem.

Rails doesn't allow controllers to access helper methods. If you want to share a method between your views and controllers, you need to define the method in your controller, and then make it available to your views with [`helper_method`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper_method):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Bbase

  # Let views access current_user
  helper_method :current_user

  def current_user
    # ...
  end

end
```

You can pass more than one method name to `helper_method` to make additional methods in your controller available to your views:

```
  helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?

  def current_user
    # ...
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
```

Comment: I knew it'd something as simple as that. I thought helper_method did the same as putting the method in the helper class, but it's not. Thanks for the quick answer and the syntax editing. :)

Comment: @meagar: I have the same problem, but adding helper method did not fix it, I have defined both my method and my helper in my class_controller not Application controller. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993912/share-method-in-view-and-controller-ruby-on-rails-4