# share method in view and controller ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method in my controller class

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    def download_sftp
        some codes here 
    end
end
```

and to be able to access it in my view,at the top of my controller I have this line

```
helper_method :download_sftp
```

when I use the following code in my view I get the undefined method download_sftp for this project

```
<tbody>
    <% @projects.each do |project| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to  'download',project.download_sftp(project) %></td>
     </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

declaring a helper_method on a controller will make it available in a view directly like any other helper (e.g `form_for` or `link_to`). However you are calling this on a project model.
So it should be:

```
<td><%= link_to  'download', download_sftp(project) %></td>
```

What is `download_sftp` supposed to do? Perhaps it even belongs into the project model.

Comment: :it did not fix the problem. Well In my project model, I have a file filed which I have uploaded on a sftp server with CarrierWave. Now I want to download the file from the sftp server with this method.

Comment: Wait do you want do download the file or just generate a link for downloading a file

Comment: generating a link  for downloading it

Comment: undefined method `download_sftp' for #<ProjectsController:0x007f863b6d3490>

Comment: sry. no idea then. It is exactly how it is specified in the doc.
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method